# Vb.net fill a structure with for cycle like in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, struct

How do you translate this to VB.Net ? I'm really not sure about how do Structs work there and I couldn't find a suitable one for me.
Could any of you please show me a way how it's done there ?

```
struct Questions
{
    public int temakor;
    public int nKerdes;
    public string kerdes;
    public string kerdes_a;
    public string kerdes_b;
    public string kerdes_c;
    public string kerdes_d;
    public char valasz;
 }
```

Then the Main()

```
    List<Questions> test_questions = new List<Questions>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"teszt_.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 130; i++)
        {
            string s = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] fields = s.Split('_'); // adatok feldarabolása
            Kerdesek uj_kerdes;
            uj_kerdes.temakor = int.Parse(fields[0]);
            uj_kerdes.nKerdes = int.Parse(fields[1]);
            uj_kerdes.kerdes = fields[2];
            uj_kerdes.kerdes_a = fields[3];
            uj_kerdes.kerdes_b = fields[4];
            uj_kerdes.kerdes_c = fields[5];
            uj_kerdes.kerdes_d = fields[6];
            uj_kerdes.valasz = char.Parse(fields[7]);
            test_questions.Add(uj_kerdes);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Kedves vizsgázó, jó tanulást a következő vizsgára");
```

Comment: (inserts mandatory warning about using `struct` incorrectly, and how having an oversized `struct` is harmful, how having a mutable `struct` is harmful, and how having `public` fields is harmful; are you *sure* you didn't mean to write a `class` with properties?)

Comment: also, is `Kerdesek` also `Questions` ?

Comment: Re the VB translaction: what have you tried? The only non-trivial thing you'd need to know is the VB keyword `Structure` - the rest... is pretty much identical to what you would *expect* it to be in VB - and virtually identical to the C#, for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, according to reflector, the C#

```
Questions q = new Questions {
    temakor = 1,
    nKerdes = 2,
    kerdes = "",
    kerdes_a = "a",
    kerdes_b = "b",
    kerdes_c = "c",
    kerdes_d = "d",
    valasz = 'v'
};
```

translates to:

```
Dim q As New Questions With { _
    .temakor = 1, _
    .nKerdes = 2, _
    .kerdes = "", _
    .kerdes_a = "a", _
    .kerdes_b = "b", _
    .kerdes_c = "c", _
    .kerdes_d = "d", _
    .valasz = "v"c _
}
```

From there it should be pretty simple. However: *that is almost certainly an inappropriate usage of a `struct`*, and it is going to actively hurt you. I strongly advise:

```
class Question
{
    public int Temakor {get;set;}
    public int KerdesInt32 {get;set;} // probably needs a better name
    public string Kerdes {get;set;}
    public string KerdesA {get;set;}
    public string KerdesB {get;set;}
    public string KerdesC {get;set;}
    public string KerdesD {get;set;}
    public char Valasz {get;set;}
 }
```

Or as an absolute worst case (and this is horrible and would need justification):

```
struct Question
{
    public readonly int Temakor;
    public readonly int KerdesInt32;
    public readonly string Kerdes, KerdesA, KerdesB, KerdesC, KerdesD
    public readonly char Valasz;
    public Question(int temakor, int kerdesInt32, ..., char valasz)
    {
        Temakor = temakor;
        KerdesInt32 = kerdesInt32;
        // ...
        Valasz = valasz;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kerdesek is also Questions. When I wrote the topic I was in a hurry, so I translated only the most important part of it to be more understandable.
Anyway. What I wanted to do is make a struct with these variables, import a txt file, and fill these variables. BUT ! I don't just want to use the struct once, but more like e.g: 10 times more or so.

- Temakor holds the topic's number
- nKerdes holds the number of the question
- kerdes holds the question itself
- kerdes_a holds the answer "a" for the question
- kerdes_b ...
- kerdes_c ...
- kerdes_d ...
- valasz holds the answer.

So when I use streamreader to read my txt file, it's lines hold the data for these variables and when a question is read-in, I read in another one until I've read the full txt file.
The reason why I use structs for this is C# is pretty simple, I guess it's the easiest way ( with LINQ ) .

Comment: A structure is nothing more than an aggregation of its public and private fields bound together with duct tape.  Passing a structure to the `Add` method passes the contents of all of its fields to that method; nothing the `Add` method receives is in any way affiliated with the structure instance from which the data was copied, so changes made to a structure after `test_questions.Add()` will not affect the data that was just added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I got to figure it out, it wasn't a big deal at all.

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
Public Structure Kerdesek
    Public hanyadik As Integer
    Public kerdes As String
    Public valaszA As String
    Public valaszB As String
    Public valaszC As String
    Public valaszD As String
    Public helyesValasz As Char
End Structure

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub BetöltésToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BetöltésToolStripMenuItem.Click
    OpenFile.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub OpenFile_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFile.FileOk
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(OpenFile.OpenFile())
    Dim firstLine As Boolean = True
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim lst As New List(Of Kerdesek)

    While Not (sr.EndOfStream)
        If (firstLine = True) Then
            row = sr.ReadLine()
            firstLine = False
        ElseIf (firstLine = False) Then
            For i = 1 To row
                Dim ujKerdes As New Kerdesek
                ujKerdes.hanyadik = sr.ReadLine()
                ujKerdes.kerdes = sr.ReadLine()
                ujKerdes.valaszA = sr.ReadLine()
                ujKerdes.valaszB = sr.ReadLine()
                ujKerdes.valaszC = sr.ReadLine()
                ujKerdes.valaszD = sr.ReadLine()
                ujKerdes.helyesValasz = sr.ReadLine()
                lst.Add(ujKerdes)
            Next i
        End If
    End While
    sr.Close()


    For Each item As Kerdesek In lst
        LabelHanyadikKerdes.Text = item.hanyadik
        LabelKerdes.Text = item.kerdes
        LabelA.Text = item.valaszA
        LabelB.Text = item.valaszB
        LabelC.Text = item.valaszC
        LabelD.Text = item.valaszD
        MessageBox.Show(item.hanyadik)
        MessageBox.Show(item.kerdes)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```